# Getting a Segmentation Fault: 11. I Have Seen Other Posts, but I Don't Know How I Can Add Memory to my Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This code is trying to check if a number is prime, I know there are more efficient methods, using sets of numbers, but I just want this to work, but I get a Segmentation fault.

If you want to test the code, it happens to me when I plug in 10000877, or any greater number.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    int prime/*???*/;
    std::cout << "Please input a number: ";
    std::cin >> prime;
    bool isPrime = true;
    int biggestFactor = ceil((prime^(1/2)));
    bool odd =  prime%2 == 1 ? true : false;
    int multiple = 0;
    int ranges[biggestFactor];
    bool boolean = false;
    for(int i = biggestFactor; i!=1; i--) {
        ranges[i-2] = ceil(prime / i);
    }
    if(odd) {
        for(int i = 1; i<prime; i++) {
            if(multiple > biggestFactor) {
                break;
            } else if(boolean) {
            } else if(i* ranges [multiple] > prime) {
                multiple++;
            } else if(i*ranges[multiple] == prime) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(prime != 2) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        std::cout << "That number is prime." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "That number is composite." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be accessing `ranges[biggestFactor]`, an index out of bounds.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks for responding, but I *think*(not sure) that I prevented that with: ```if(multiple > biggestFactor) {
                break;
            }```

Comment: `prime^(1/2)` is not doing what you think it is. `^` is the bitwise XOR in C and C++. Your code is also C++, not C, so please don't tag it. Futhermore you can easily find this issue by using a debugger. Please learn to use one.

Comment: `int ranges[biggestFactor];` could get very large and cause a stack overflow. Consider using a `std::vector` instead. With `vector` you can use the `at` method to see if there are any out of bounds accesses.

Comment: `if(multiple > biggestFactor)` doesn't preclude `multiple == biggestFactor`

Comment: Also note, that `int ranges[biggestFactor];` is a variable length array (VLA) which is not standard C++ but a `gcc` extension.

Comment: Also: Dividing two integers gives again an integer (with the decimals from the division cut of), e.g. `1/2` is `0` and `ceil` in `ceil(prime / i)` is not doing anything besides changing the type to `double` and then back to `int` at the assignment following it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from noted fact that prime^(1/2) is not square root of prime, your code (even though it's wrong) sort of works. You just overestimate the square root by using prime instead (the 1/2 is converted to int which is 0 and XOR with it is itself).

It works on small numbers, I tried.

Now with the large numbers you are running out of memory here, trying to allocate 4 * 10000877 bytes

> ```
> int ranges[biggestFactor];
> ```